# use point to present laserscan data?

Tags: laser, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am new to opengl, and I have some questions about presenting laserscan data on android. In the tutorial code (android_tutorial_teleop), triangle fan shape is used to present laser scan data. Why triangle fan shape is chosen here to present the data? Can we use just point shape instead?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36660/use-point-to-present-laserscan-data?/) by [ira](https://answers.ros.org/users/1953/ira/) on ROS Answers with karma: 106 on 2012-06-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [weiin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1505/weiin/) on 2012-06-17**:
which tutorial code are you using? rviz is usually used to visualize data in ros. for laserscan, http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/DisplayTypes/LaserScan shows the available rendering styles.

**Comment by [ira](https://answers.ros.org/users/1953/ira/) on 2012-06-21**:
Sorry, forgot to mention that. I am using android_tutorial_teleop to visualize laser scan data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's visualization, so it's up to you. Choose whatever you like. Points are a common display for laser scans. One reason for choosing a triangle fan might be that it appears "filled out" and thus is better visible.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0